# Authorize.net: Manually re-charge a client after a failed ARB transaction

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net

We use Authorize.net's Automated Recurring Billing and when a client's subscription payment fails is there a way to manually re-attempt to charge the client for the subscription? The only way I've ever been able been able to make it work is to get their CC info and manually key in a transaction but for instances where a client's car simply had insufficient funds/etc it's a pain (and far from ideal) to have to ask them to re-enter their CC info so we can attempt to charge them again. Is there a way to trigger ARB to retry the transaction or create a one-off AIM transaction from the subscription w/o requiring their CC info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After research I've determined there are two options:

1. Store credit card #s encrypted
2. Do nothing.

Since storing them encrypted is more than I wanted to mess with at this time I'm going to have to go for option 2.

Authorize.net has a pretty weak API. If anyone has a recommendation for a payment gateway whose API isn't in the stone age I'd love to hear about it.

Cheers,
Dan

Answer (score 6):

I think there is some real misinformation on this question.

Authorize.NET allows you to "Store" customer billing information (CC info, etc) on their system (avoiding all the bad juju that happens when you store CC info locally).

You can do this using the `CreateCustomerProfile` method.

The response from this method is basically some key(s) to uniquely identify their account in Authorize.NET's system.

Use that account ID you can bill their CC ad-hoc whenever/however you'd like using the `CreateCustomerProfileTransaction` method.

If one of their payments fails due to, for example, not enough funds - then you can try to rebill them later using this approach.

If, however, their CC info changes - you need to let the customer update their CC info - and use Authorize.NET's methods to update their profile.

Comment: The latter part is true for CIM but not true for ARB. ps - I'd love to switch to CIM but we have too many customers being billed via ARB and alas there is no migration. I fear it would go like this between our Cust Svs Rep and our customer...  Rep: Please come back and re-enter your CC info. Customer (now alarmed): Why? Rep: uh... no reason...uh, we'll be able to bill you better.  Customer: uh...

Comment: ps - I haven't tried this but an Authorize.net rep told me you can create an ARB from a transaction that is less than 90days old (online - not sure about api).

Answer (score 2):

Use the Authorize.net [CIM API](http://developer.authorize.net/api/cim/) to store your customer credit card information rather than storing it locally. If for some reason an ARB transaction fails, you can use the CIM API to charge your customer on a one-time basis (cf create_customer_profile_transaction in the CIM API).

Comment: Two issues with this: 1. if the card is expired then it is expired in CIM, too. 2. CIM is an additional cost.

Answer (score 1):

If the transaction failed because the card is no longer valid, expired, or at its limit, then you won't be able to recharge it even if you had the credit card information. You would need to have the customer provide you with a new credit card anyway so you can update their subscription and charge them for the missed payment at that point in time.